# echo a customized message with VIM editor

Tags: vim, vimrc

How can I deltect if there is a file modification in VIM upon exiting (`:q`)?
If there is a file modification Vim echos

```
E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)
```

I want to override this message with a custom message and an action similar to

```
File modified: Do you wish to save the file? (y)Yes (n)No (c)Cancel
```

I have modified Vim's behavior to save file on `Ctrl-s` and quit on `Ctrl-w`

Now I am looking for a solution if the file is already modified and user is quitting it with Ctrl-w I want Vim to prompt to save.

Here is the content of my .vimrc file:

```
map <C-S> :w<CR>
imap <C-S> <Esc>:w<CR>i

map <C-w> :q<CR>
imap <C-w> <Esc>:q<CR>
```

Comment: What about using `:confirm quit`?

Comment: @danielkullmann Works!! never knew about that. However, how can I map that to Ctrl-w to confirm quit when there is a modification in file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `:confirm quit`, e.g.

```
map <C-w> :confirm quit<CR>
```

By the way: `C-w` is a bad choice for a shortcut, because it is used as the start of other shortcuts, e.g. `C-w v` for splitting vertically. That's why you experience a short delay before the dialog pops open: after you press `C-w`, vim waits a short time for other keypresses, before it decides that you really just wanted to press `C-w`.

Comment: Awesome. and thanks for the tip. will avoid using Ctrl-w.. How about Ctrl-q?? Any thoughts?

Comment: See `:help c_CTRL-Q`. Looks fine, if you're using the GUI version of vim, which you seem to do (Ctrl-S is also used for terminal control flow).

Answer (score 2):

You've already got a specific answer.  Here's a generic one:

You can find examples (and complete working packages) of pretty nearly every kind of vim enhancement you can think of at http://www.vim.org/scripts/index.php